# Profile integration with Google+, Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc

Tags: facebook, authentication, twitter, google-plus, linkedin-api

I'm creating a website and I would like for users to be able to log in with more common accounts like Google+, Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc. How would I achieve this? Is there any language that makes it easier to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The companies you mentioned, Facebook, Linkedin, Twitter, etc. have API's ready-made to help you achieve this.  Visit this link to look at facebook's 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login
They also have some rules that apply (how many requests per minute, etc.) and may want you to pay if you exceed the limits they set forth.

As for the language: Javascript if probably your best bet for connecting with API's.  There are other languages that will allow you to do this as well, but if you run into problems along the way, you will find more people who can help you if you are using Javascript because it is the most common.
Jquery (a Javascript library) will enable you to use AJAX to connect with API's, but this is just one example of the many options you will have available to you if you use Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

No special language needed. You should simply use the "API's" of each social network. They all come with good documentation.

Else if you don't wanna put your hands in the engine, you could also use an automated solution like [social login and registration tools](http://www.janrain.com/)